# Собрать composer.json из папки vendor

Tags: php, composer

Достался проект с папкой `vendor`. А вот файлов `composer.json` или `composer.lock` "не завезли". Можно ли собрать `composer.json` из папки `vendor`?

*Помимо того что-бы лазить по папкам и вручеую вписывать зависимости*

P.S. Зачем? Мне нужен еще пакет и хочу его включить в стандартный `vendor/autoload.php`, если можно как то подругому подлючить еще пакет, тоже вариант (перекинуть вендор в подпапку, создать все чистое и подключть к нему старый автолоад, вариант конечно, ноо...)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать кoманду

```
composer show --installed
```

Она выведет список всех установленых пакетов из папки *vendor*

Выводит список вида

```
doctrine/cache                       1.11.3    PHP Doctrine Cache library is a popular cache implementation that supports many different drivers such as redis, memcache, apc, mongodb and others.
doctrine/collections                 1.6.8     PHP Doctrine Collections library that adds additional functionality on top of PHP arrays.
doctrine/common                      2.13.3    PHP Doctrine Common project is a library that provides additional functionality that other Doctrine projects depend on such as better reflection support, persistence interfa...
doctrine/dbal                        2.13.5    Powerful PHP database abstraction layer (DBAL) with many features for database schema introspection and management.
doctrine/deprecations                v0.5.3    A small layer on top of trigger_error(E_USER_DEPRECATED) or PSR-3 logging with options to disable all deprecations or selectively for packages.
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             1.12.9    Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       1.4.0     Symfony Bundle for Doctrine Cache
```

Если пакетов не так много, то наверное можно и руками список составить. Если много, то по идее можно распарсить вывод и собрать список в формате, который подойдет для *composer.json*

Вероятней всего композер откажется работать без файла *composer.json*. Но его можно создать вручную - простейший. Или с помощью команды `composer init`